# How can I delete more than one element of a list with one command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How can I delete more than one element of a list with one command?
Considering the fact that list.remove(item) removes only one item, I need to remove a list of items with one command.

List I have:

```
 MyList = [{'level': '46', 'Kullanıcı Adı': '  .', 'Mesaj': 
'jgfkslkjghfdkskhjnfdsfhkjn'}, 
{'level': '46', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'abc', 'Mesaj': 'Ya jager 
ndkslsjfodldke'}, 
{'level': '70', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'ɛმИ', 'Mesaj': ' ahahahfdjggsgd'}, 
{'level': '54', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'Undyvallet', 'Mesaj': 
'afdsfadsfdsfdsfds'}, 
{'level': '52', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'Lylz', 'Mesaj': 'hüptürük'}, 
{'level': '59', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'KTeX', 'Mesaj': 
'jıljkdfvbfdjfdffdblkdbnfd'}, 
{'level': '61', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'Emnvdar', 'Mesaj': 'mert efsane ya'}, 
{'level': '59', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'Emnvdar', 'Mesaj': 'ahhqhaha'}]

MyList.remove('list of items')
```

does not work.

Any solution?

Comment: Assuming your list is either called `a` or you're trying `del MyList[7]`, either should work just fine. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: how do you want to identify the elements to remove? Index? key? value?  Please be specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another list and call difference function for two sets like this:

```
MyList = [{'level': '46', 'Kullanıcı Adı': '  .', 'Mesaj': 'jgfkslkjghfdkskhjnfdsfhkjn'}, 
{'level': '46', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'abc', 'Mesaj': 'Ya jager ndkslsjfodldke'}, 
{'level': '70', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'ɛმИ', 'Mesaj': ' ahahahfdjggsgd'}, 
{'level': '54', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'Undyvallet', 'Mesaj': 'afdsfadsfdsfdsfds'}, 
{'level': '52', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'Lylz', 'Mesaj': 'hüptürük'}, 
{'level': '59', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'KTeX', 'Mesaj': 'jıljkdfvbfdjfdffdblkdbnfd'}, 
{'level': '61', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'Emnvdar', 'Mesaj': 'mert efsane ya'}, 
{'level': '59', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'Emnvdar', 'Mesaj': 'ahhqhaha'}]

anotherList=[{
{'level': '54', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'Undyvallet', 'Mesaj': 'afdsfadsfdsfdsfds'}, 
{'level': '52', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'Lylz', 'Mesaj': 'hüptürük'}, 
{'level': '59', 'Kullanıcı Adı': 'Emnvdar', 'Mesaj': 'ahhqhaha'}]

print(set(MyList).difference(anotherList))
```